# Append 2 queries result in repeating of data from first query

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I am new to PowerBI and trying to append 2 queries into new query. But it is repeating data from the first query set and not creating an Append(I think i am correct if it is same as `UNION` in SQL). Here are the snapshots:

**Query1**
[image]

**Query2**
[image]

**Resulting Append**
[image]

Let me know what is wrong in this

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In your data set it is doing a Union on the data as you mentioned. Append in Power Query will NOT remove duplicates (like a UNION ALL in SQL), you will have to use a 'Group By' step or 'Remove Duplicates' step after the append to remove the duplicates

Hope that helps

Comment: Well I agree with repeated values but why second table is not showing up except its first column. In first table we have 6 rows and in second we have 12, its union should be 18 rows, but here it is 12 rows. 6 rows from first table repeated only with values in first column changed

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Edit Queries` and select your Query1 then go to `Home > Append Queries as New`. Chose your two tables (Query1 and Query2) and hit OK.

This should exactly append the two queries, without repeating any duplicates.

Comment: I did exactly the same thing and result is this as shown in 3rd image

Comment: Same column names? Only explanation left, is that you have duplicate rows in your Query1 and Query2.

Comment: yep i verified the column names and they exactly match. Also rows are what you see in above images. Nothing is repeated as i have already firltered duplicate rows

Comment: Can you show your code from the advanced query editor? From Query1, Query2 and the new appended one.